# Will prestashop addon for 1.5.x work on 1.6.x?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I need to install an eway module in my prestashop v1.6. I found [this](http://addons.prestashop.com/en/payments-gateways-prestashop-modules/10956-eway-australia.html) by Prestashop Community which says it supports up to v1.5.6.1. I found [here](http://www.prestashop.com/blog/en/answers-to-your-questions-about-prestashop-1-6/) that modules developed by prestashop will work on new version itself. And usually the core stuff are same as per the link as well. So does that mean this addon will work on v1.6? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will most likely work, I had a 1.5 module and ported it to 1.6 and all I have changed is the css. I guess the only problem is the overrides because these are modified core methods that may vary from version to version

Comment: eWAY supply a free module which is Prestashop 1.6 compatible in their [partner portal](http://www.eway.com.au/developers) - or ask their support for a copy.

Comment: The module did work on 1.6 but I was not aware of eway providing the free module for 1.6. I'll check with their support.